# mouse event not working with GCompound objects

Tags: java, mouseevent

I am learning Java following class CS106A and am having issues that GCompound object is not interacting with mouse events.

I noticed the issue while doing programming exercises in "the Art and Science of Java" and couldn't figure out the reason. So i tried to copy the sample code of the book and tried to run it in eclipse, and they didn't work either.

Below is GFace class defined in the book that extends GCompound.

```
    import acm.graphics.*;

    public class GFace extends GCompound{

/** Constants specifying feature size as a fraction of the head size*/
private static final double EYE_WIDTH = 0.15;
private static final double EYE_HEIGHT = 0.15;
private static final double NOSE_WIDTH = 0.15;
private static final double NOSE_HEIGHT = 0.10;
private static final double MOUTH_WIDTH = 0.50;
private static final double MOUTH_HEIGHT = 0.03;


/** Construct a new GFace object with the specified dimensions. */
public GFace (double width, double height){
    head = new GOval (width, height);
    leftEye = new GOval (EYE_WIDTH * width, EYE_HEIGHT * height);
    rightEye = new GOval (EYE_WIDTH * width, EYE_HEIGHT * height);
    nose = createNose (NOSE_WIDTH * width, NOSE_HEIGHT * height);
    mouth = new GRect(MOUTH_WIDTH * width, MOUTH_HEIGHT * height);
    add(head, 0, 0);
    add(leftEye, 0.25 * width - EYE_WIDTH * width / 2,
                 0.25 * height - EYE_HEIGHT * height / 2);
    add(rightEye, 0.75 * width - EYE_WIDTH * width / 2,
                  0.25 * height - EYE_HEIGHT * height / 2);
    add(nose, 0.50 * width, 0.50 * height);
    add(mouth, 0.50 * width - MOUTH_WIDTH * width / 2,
               0.75 * height - MOUTH_HEIGHT * height / 2);  
}

/** creates a triangle for the nose*/
private GPolygon createNose(double width, double height){
    GPolygon poly = new GPolygon();
    poly.addVertex(0, -height/2);
    poly.addVertex(width / 2, height / 2);
    poly.addVertex(-width / 2, height / 2);
    return poly;
}

/*instance variables*/  
private GOval head;
private GOval leftEye, rightEye;
private GPolygon nose;
private GRect mouth;    
}
```

and then below program is supposed to create a GFace object on Canvas so that user can drag it around with mouse. But, when i ran the program, the GFace object on canvas does not respond to my mouse, while GRect object can ne dragged on canvas. I've also added a rectangle to see if by clicking on the GFace, the program returns null, as suggested in the comment(thanks for the advice!), and it does. It just seems the GCompound object cannot be selected.

```
    import acm.graphics.*;
    import acm.program.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import acm.util.*;

public class DragFace extends GraphicsProgram{


/** Width of the face */
private static final double FACE_WIDTH = 200;

/** Height of the face */
private static final double FACE_HEIGHT = 300;

/** Runs the program */
public void run(){
    /*added a filled rectangle to the screen.
     * if no object selected and returns null,
     * rectangle changes color randomly*/
    add(temp);
    temp.setFillColor(Color.RED);
    temp.setFilled(true);
    
    GFace face = new GFace(FACE_WIDTH, FACE_HEIGHT);
    double x1 = (getWidth() - FACE_WIDTH) / 2;
    double y1 = (getHeight() - FACE_HEIGHT) / 2;
    add(face, x1, y1);
    
    GObject rect = new GRect(FACE_WIDTH, FACE_HEIGHT);
    double x = (getWidth() - FACE_WIDTH) / 2;
    double y = (getHeight() - FACE_HEIGHT) / 2;
    add(rect, x, y);
    rect.setColor(Color.RED);
    addMouseListeners();
}

/** called on mouse press to record the coordinates of the click */
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
    lastX = e.getX();
    lastY = e.getY();
    gobj = getElementAt(lastX, lastY);
    
    /* if no object selected and returns null,
     * rectangle changes color randomly each time */
    if(gobj == null){
        temp.setFillColor(rgen.nextColor());
    }
}

/** called on mouse drag to reposition the object*/
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
    if(gobj != null){
        gobj.move(e.getX() - lastX, e.getY() - lastY);
        lastX = e.getX();
        lastY = e.getY();
    }
}

/** called on mouse click to move this object to the front*/
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
    if(gobj != null) gobj.sendToFront();
}



/*private state*/
private GObject gobj; /*the object being dragged*/
private double lastX; /*the last mouse X position*/
private double lastY; /*the last mouse Y position*/
private GRect temp = new GRect(0,0,100,100);/* private rectangle*/
private RandomGenerator rgen = new RandomGenerator();
}
```

MY question is

1. does GCompound object works as a unit like a GRect? If so, can can anyone point out the cause of the issue in the code above? I don't know if it's my software that's causing the issue, or if I am missing something with the use of GCompound class.
2. the Gface is supposed to be centered on Canvas, but somehow it shows up on the button right corner. The x- and y- coordinate of the Gface is always twice of the coordinate specified in the add call. Any idea how this might have happened?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the reason that your first program doesn't work that `getElementAt` is returning `null`, or that `move` is not working on `GCompound`? In either case I suggest that you look at the Javadoc and source code of `GCompound`.

Comment: @tgdavies Thanks for the response. It could be, but i am not sure how to check that. I tried clicking everywhere inside the GCompound, but it simply won't move. When i create one GCompound object and one GRect object in the same program, the GRect object is always responding to drag.

Comment: Add some code to print a message if `getElemenAt` ever returns a non-null value. That will tell you which problem you have. Have you looked at the `GCompound` javadoc and source?

Comment: @tgdavies thanks for the advice. It does return a `null` value whenever I click on the `GCompound` object. And Javadoc says the `GCompound`  class defines graphic object consists of collection of multiple objects and allows the `getElementAt` method.

Comment: Both your `DragTest` programs above create a `GRect`. Neither creates a `GFace`.

Comment: @tgdavies thanks for the continued response. Really appreciate it. I've removed one version of the program and  created a `GFace` and a `GRect` in the same program. As I kept testing it, the `GFace` was moving for a brief moment, only when i click on the top left portion of the object, which is outside of the graphics. And it moves twice the amount of my mouse movement. Really confused at the moment.